# Unable to send attachment with the email using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, my objective is to send attachment with the email. For emailing purpose, we're using sendgrid and for uploading files or attachments we're `sendgrid mail helper attachment` in backend. But i couldn't able to upload file, i can send only email but i couldn't able to send email with attachment. I couldn't able to figure it out where i'm going wrong. I have been struggling from couple of weeks but couldn't figure out where i'm going wrong.

Here is the code:

```
fileChange = e => {
    this.setState(
      { file: e.target.files[0], fileName: e.target.files[0].name },
      () => {
        console.log(
          "File chosen --->",
          this.state.file,
          console.log("File name  --->", this.state.fileName)
        );
      }
    );
  };

 <Button.Content hidden>Choose a File</Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  hidden
                  onChange={this.fileChange}
                />
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  label="File Chosen: "
                  placeholder="browse your file system"
                  readOnly
                  value={this.state.fileName}
                />
```

Can anyone help me in this query please?

Answer (score 1):

you are passing file but you set wrong content-type.

> headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

Please use the following line instead above line

> headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}

Comment: I'm getting error as ***the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)***

Comment: Perhaps this is back end error. you have to debug in backend.

Comment: Backend people checked with that and moreover in swagger, it is working fine. main thing is in sendgrid we have to use `sendgrid mail helper attachment` for file upload, i.e we need to pass the path. Sendgrid playing a bit different thing in sending file with email. i couldn;t able to find the format to send it through frontend